# request() and fs.createReadStream() not returning the "right" values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, request, fs

I'm trying to scrape the content of a webpage with Node.js and compare it to a copy of the same page I have stored as a file, like so:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var request = require("request");
var archive = ["./archive.html", "http://praguerace.com/comic/archive"];

request(archive[1], //request Prague Race's archive
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (fs.createReadStream(archive[0]) == body) //if no change occurred
            console.log("checkpoint 1");
        else
            console.log("checkpoint 2");
    }
);
```

I already have the Request module installed (properly), and am not using Express.

The problem is that the script keeps printing "checkpoint 2", it's as if the response I get from the server I'm trying to scrape keeps changing, or Node doesn't know what `==` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fs.createReadStream(archive[0]) return a stream and not the content

Use stream event to retrieve the content, readStream.on('open', 'data', etc...

Or just use readFile or readFileSync

Async version :

```
request(archive[1], //request Prague Race's archive
function (error, response, body) {
   fs.readFile(archive[0], "utf8", function(err, data){
     if(data  == body)
       ....
     else
        ....
    });
});
```

Sync version

```
request(archive[1], //request Prague Race's archive
function (error, response, body) {
     if(fs.readFileSync(archive[0], "utf8")  == body)
       ....
     else
        ....
});
```